# How to install my application

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation

I just created a simple application which creates a file on my desktop and writes "HAHA" in it. I made it in C++ and used g++ to get a binary. It works but it's not really "installed" on linux mint.

So I wondered how do I do that? How can I tell linux mint to show this in my menu where all my installed applications are listed?

I heard something about moving it into /usr/bin with a bash script. I moved the application to /usr/bin with terminal but there were no changes (the app is in the directory but it's not displayed in my menu). Or do I have to restart linux mint?

Maybe you could send me a link to a good tutorial. I need some help...

Comment: Just move in into `~/bin` and ensure that this directory includes in your `PATH`. Only if your `/home` mounted with `noexec` then you should move this file somewhere into `/opt/bin`

Comment: @Eddy_Em I did that but it doesn't show up in the application list again =/ Or what do you mean exactly with "ensure that this directory includes in your PATH" ?

Comment: @Davlog to achieve that, you need to created the .desktop file with information where you executable file is and maybe a icon. If you want to really "install" then you have to to all of the above and create a deb package.

Comment: @AlexandreAlves well how do I do that? Is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: search online. I don't know what DE you are using or check already a existing .desktop file to see what it should contain. Creting a deb package again the same, a quick search will lead you to several tutorials...

Answer (score 0):

You can either add your executable to /bin or /usr/bin (or any other path in your [PATH Environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29), you can check by entering `echo "$PATH"`) or you can add the directory to your PATH (`export PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/dir/with/executables`)